# An error occured synchronizing windows with time.windows.com

Tags: windows-server-2008, w32time

Okay so I've tried stopping/registering the win32tm service on this `Windows Server 2008 Enterprise` Computer.

```
C:\Users\Administrator>net stop w32time
The Windows Time service is stopping.
The Windows Time service was stopped successfully.

C:\Users\Administrator>w32tm /unregister
The following error occurred: Access is denied. (0x80070005)

C:\Users\Administrator>w32tm /unregister
W32Time successfully unregistered.

C:\Users\Administrator>w32tm /register
W32Time successfully registered.

C:\Users\Administrator>net start w32time
The Windows Time service is starting.
The Windows Time service was started successfully.

(Source : http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winserverDS/thread/9bdfc2cc-4775-4435-8868-57d214e1e3ba/)
```

And I get this error from the `Date and Time`, `Internet Time` tab (After also following the steps [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/816042/how-to-configure-an-authoritative-time-server-in-windows-server)).

[image]
<sub>(source: [iforce.co.nz](http://iforce.co.nz/i/f513533m.bry.jpg))</sub>

I've even tried the [Atomic Time Clock Worldtimeserver](https://www.worldtimeserver.com/current_time_in_US-TX.aspx) and I get the error `The following error occurred: The specified module could not be found. (0x8007007E)`.

I've also disabled the `Windows Firewall`, that might of been blocking the synchronization.

[image: windows firewall]
<sub>(source: [iforce.co.nz](http://iforce.co.nz/i/e2s2wjoe.4hg.jpg))</sub>

I've done a file scan with `sfc /scannow` that came back with no errors.

```
C:\Users\Administrator>sfc /scannow

Beginning system scan.  This process will take some time.

Beginning verification phase of system scan.
Verification 100% complete.

Windows Resource Protection did not find any integrity violations.

C:\Users\Administrator>
```

But I'm not having much luck. Is there anyway lo possibly solve this? or is the time.windows.com servers unsupported? because the software is from 2008? (I really don't know :/), My ping result to `time.windows.com`

```
C:\Users\Administrator>ping time.windows.com

Pinging time.microsoft.akadns.net [65.55.21.22] with 32 bytes of data:
Request timed out.
Request timed out.
Request timed out.
Request timed out.

Ping statistics for 65.55.21.22:
Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 0, Lost = 4 (100% loss),
```

And tracert result

> C:\Users\Administrator>tracert time.windows.com
>
> Tracing route to time.microsoft.akadns.net [65.55.21.24]
>   over a maximum of 30 hops:
>
> 1     1 ms    <1 ms    <1 ms  192.168.1.1
>    2    32 ms    31 ms    32 ms  be2-100.bras1wtc.wlg.vf.net.nz [203.109.129.113]
>
> 3    31 ms    32 ms    31 ms  be5-100.ppnzwtc01.wlg.vf.net.nz.129.109.203.in-a
>   ddr.arpa [203.109.129.114]
>    4    31 ms    31 ms    31 ms  gi0-2-0-3.ppnzwtc01.wlg.vf.net.nz.180.109.203.in
>   -addr.arpa [203.109.180.210]
>    5    31 ms    31 ms    30 ms  gi0-2-0-3.ppnzwtc02.wlg.vf.net.nz [203.109.180.2
>   09]
>    6   167 ms   166 ms   166 ms  ip-141.199.31.114.VOCUS.net.au [114.31.199.141]
>
> 7   175 ms   175 ms   175 ms  microsoft.com.any2ix.coresite.com [206.223.143.1
>   43]
>    8   177 ms   180 ms   176 ms  xe-7-0-2-0.by2-96c-1a.ntwk.msn.net [207.46.42.17
>   6]
>    9   205 ms   205 ms   204 ms  xe-10-0-2-0.co1-96c-1b.ntwk.msn.net [207.46.45.3
>   1]
>   10     *        *        *     Request timed out.
>   11     *        *        *     Request timed out.
>   12     *        *        *     Request timed out.
>   13     *        *        *     Request timed out.
>   14     *        *        *     Request timed out.
>   15     *        *        *     Request timed out.
>   16  ^C

And nslookup

```
C:\Users\Administrator>nslookup time.windows.com
Server:  UnKnown
Address:  192.168.1.1

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:    time.microsoft.akadns.net
Address:  65.55.21.22
Aliases:  time.windows.com
```

Comment: It might be worth running Wireshark to see what's happening at the traffic level.

Comment: What should I be looking for? on wireshark?

Comment: Watch the NTP traffic to see how far it's getting and whether or not there are any replies, which will be ignored if they take longer than the timeout period.

Comment: Only you can make that assessment. However, rather than format and reinstall from scratch I would first try in in-place reinstall, which generally leaves most settings and configurations intact. Whether that's possible with Server 2008 I can't say.

Comment: You either misspelled time.windows.com in your tracert or you've got a DNS problem. If you run nslookup for time.windows.com does it resolve?

Comment: @JohnGardeniers "NTP" isn't a valid display filter: "NTP" is neither a field nor a protocol name.

Comment: Ok, so no DNS problem. While ping and traceret aren't really the right tools to troubleshoot a time sync issue, they can illuminate potential routing problems. As it is though, I get the same tracert results as you. My tracert dies as it enters the MSN network, which tells me that routing is OK but that they block incoming ICMP Echo Request traffic to the time.windows.com server cluster.

Comment: Filter on UDP port 123.

Comment: The windows firewall and router firewalls are both disabled

Comment: @joeqwerty `"udp port 123" isn't a valid display filter: "port" was unexpected in this context.` that command doesn't work on wireshark :-/

Comment: Oh sorry. I forgot you were using Wireshark. I was using Microsoft Network Monitor (which I personally find easier to use).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Its a little late, but you often get that error if your clock is wrong. Shockingly enough, you need to set the clock to a *nearly correct* time for it to synchronise properly.

Its probably so that if you DID get time related wierdness regularly , you will get off your rear and work out why its happening - its often due to a dead or weak bios battery.

Comment: How do your pings timeout when your clock is off?

Comment: A few years on.... I don't remember

Answer (score 3):

Here's a better and pretty standard option... use the public NTP Pool or the USNO Master Clock for time synchronization.  If you change your time clock source do you still have the same problem?  Have you tried testing any external time source manually?

Comment: I've tried with [http://time.xmission.com](http://time.xmission.com), [time.nist.gov](http://time.nist.gov), [time-nw.nist.gov](http://time-nw.nist.gov), [time-a.nist.gov](http://time-a.nist.gov) and [time-b.nist.gov](http://time-b.nist.gov) they all give me timeout errors.

Comment: By the way I don't know what public NTP or USNO Master Clock, if you could provide some references? that would be nice. Regards

Comment: I've ran the command `net time /setsntp:"0.pool.ntp.org 1.pool.ntp.org 2.pool.ntp.org"` and `w32tm /config /syncfromflags:manual /manualpeerlist:0.pool.ntp.org,1.pool.ntp.org,2.pool.ntp.org,3.pool.ntp.org` and I'm still unable to sync.. :/

Comment: If you are unable to sync with any of the public NTP servers (and assuming they resolve to valid IPs using the nameserver on your network) you have a network level issue. Check all firewalls between you and the internet (a wireshark traffic dump like John suggested in his comments on the question would be a good idea too - if the firewalls are returning the ICMP "Communication prohibited by filter" message that would tell you which firewall is saying no.)

Comment: `0.nz.pool.ntp.org`. If that doesn't work, you almost certainly have a firewall problem.

Answer (score 1):

Is this server part of a domain?  It's best practice to sync from the domain environment.

Is it a Hyper-V virtual machine? If it is you need to make sure you have the "Time Synchronization" Integration service disabled.

When you run:

```
W32tm /query /configuration
```

Do you see all [local] settings? If not that may be an indicator that Group Policy is setting the time settings.

Have you tried running the commands to sync from an external time source manually?

```
W32tm /config /syncfromflags:manual /manualpeerlist:"us.pool.ntp.org"
W32tm /config /reliable:yes
W32tm /config /update
Net stop w32time && Net start w32time (Alternatively, reboot if you can)
W32tm /resync /rediscover
```

Answer (score -1):

I downloaded http://www.karenware.com/powertools/ptsync.asp and it now synchronizing